# How to HIdeTitle Bar in Xamarin Forms in WPF in FormsContentPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, desktop-application

I am currently working on a Xamarin Forms project using Fresh MVVM, and I am displaying a player page on the WPF platform using FormsContentPage. However, I am facing difficulty hiding the title bar as my page is a FormsContentPage.

I have tried

```
 this.ParentWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
 this.ParentWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
 this.ParentWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
 this.ParentWindow.Topmost = false;
 this.ParentWindow.Visibility = Visibility. Visible;

 this.ParentWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
 this.ParentWindow.Left = 0;
 this.ParentWindow.Top = 0;
 this.ParentWindow.Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
 this.ParentWindow.Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight,
```

I have also used  `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`
but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Could someone provide guidance on how to hide the title bar when using FormsContentPage on the WPF platform in Xamarin. Forms with Fresh MVVM?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeEWc.jpg)
as shown my image I want to hide blue title bar make my player page on full screen mode

Comment: Could this maybe help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025463/how-to-remove-huge-title-bar-from-xamarin-forms-wpf-application

Comment: or maybe try "this.ParentWindow.ShowTitleBar = false;"

Comment: tried...  doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: "this.ParentWindow.ShowTitleBar = false;"  there is no property ShowTitleBar